# Is it possible to redirect request from middleware in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

What I'm trying to achieve is this:
When someone visits: `smartphone.webshop.nl/home/index`
I want to redirect this from middle ware to: `webshop.nl/smartphone/home/index`

I want to do this because I want to create a generic controller which get data from database based on `sub-domein`. So I need all the calls come to the same controller.

This is my middleware now:

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var subDomain = string.Empty;

        var host = context.Request.Host.Host;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(host))
        {
            subDomain = host.Split('.')[0]; // Redirect to this subdomain
        }

        return this._next(context);
    }
```

How can I redirect and how should my `controller/mvc` config look like?

I'm pretty new to .net core so please be clear in your answers. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at `context.Response.Redirect` ?

Comment: @ColinM Yes I did. That returns a 302 and rewrites the url. But I don't want that. I want the url to be  as it is and redirect it only in code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's called URL Rewriting and ASP.NET Core already have [special middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting) for that (in package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite`).

On your configuration file, you can have something like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using RewriteRules;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
var options = new RewriteOptions()
             .AddRewrite(@"^smartphone.webshop.nl/(.*)", "webshop.nl/smartphone/$1", skipRemainingRules: true);

app.UseRewriter(options);
```

If you want to do something more elaborated, you can either [implement a method-base rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#method-based-rule) or [check source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Middleware/Rewrite/src) and write your own middleware.

Comment: Thank you very much @Dmitry

Comment: Source code link is dead @Dmitry. Can you please update the url.

Comment: Why don't you show an example on how to do it here?

Comment: I just edited the answer, adding an example of how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 38):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Test.Middleware
{
    public class TestMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, AppDbContext dataContext, UserManager<User> userManager, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {

            // Redirect to login if user is not authenticated. This instruction is neccessary for JS async calls, otherwise everycall will return unauthorized without explaining why
            if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && httpContext.Request.Path.Value != "/Account/Login")
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
            }

            // Move forward into the pipeline
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
    public static class TestMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseTestMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<TestMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution if you require more control over when to redirect as I required, as opposed to a fixed constant redirect! Thanks!

Comment: For this Redirect to execute successfully, you can't allow the code to hit the `_next(httpContext);`

Comment: I recently needed a customizable redirect middleware, maybe update the code as mentioned by @AndrewBoyd with a return; after httpContext.Response.Redirect...

Answer (score 0):

You can review the code below

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
 {
// Do work that can write to the Response.
context.Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://stackoverflow.com/");
await next.Invoke();
   // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
  });
```