# How to implement a setup page in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-configuration

I want to create something like an installation page for a web application. For example, a page where the user can choose which database to use (Microsoft SQL Server, Postgres, etc.) in order to establish a connection to the database.

Do you have any ideas how to implement such page? Are there any projects with such a page?

Comment: @JeremyCaney, how can I do this with action filters?

Comment: Check out `PostConfigure<TOptions>` methods for configuration validation.  https://andrewlock.net/delaying-strongly-typed-options-configuration-using-postconfigure-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: @JeremyCaney, and last question: how to dynamically select database? I mean how to use different DBs (MS SQL Server, Postgres...)

Comment: @alexseybobrovitch: Per your request, I've reorganized my feedback as an answer. As part of that, I filled in some of the gaps, added additional links, and expanded on my explanation. (I've also deleted my above comments, since they are now redundant.) That should help you, and others with this question, get started on this type of project. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really broad question, and is highly dependent on your application. E.g., where are you storing your connections string? When and where are you first accessing it? I can provide a broad overview of how to approach this, however, alongside some references that will help you get started.

### Basic Steps

1. Identify that configuration data is missing
2. Redirect to a setup page
3. Collect the missing configuration data from the user
4. Save the missing configuration data to your configuration store
5. Redirect back to the original

Addressing all of these is more involved than any one Stack Overflow answer, but I can provide some pointers that will help with the most likely stumbling blocks.

### Intercepting Requests

The first requirement is to detect whether configuration data is missing and to redirect to a setup page. This is typically done via some type of ASP.NET Core [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Middleware are a bit more flexible as they can happen earlier and cover a broader scope of requests, while filters are easier to write as they have easy access to more contextual information about the request.

#### Resource Filters

A common approach to this is to create an [ASP.NET Core Resource Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#resource-filters) or that checks for the presence of key configuration resources—such as a connection string—and, if they’re not present, redirect the user to a setup page. A similar approach can be taken with [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62511093/3025856).

#### Exception Filter

Another approach is to throw e.g., a custom `UnconfiguredApplicationException` at every point where you need a configuration variable, but one isn’t present. Then, handle that exception globally using [a custom Exception Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters), [a custom Middleware component](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/10/02/aspnet-core-31-global-error-handler-tutorial), or [the existing `UseExceptionHandler` middleware](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/global-error-handling-in-asp-net-core-5/). This requires more code since you must add the check at every point where you depend on configuration data, but prevents the need to proactively validate your configuration data for every request.

#### Implementation

The [Microsoft documentation for filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) offers some good guidance for the basic construction of Resource and Exception Filters. It also includes an example for an Action Filter, which can be added to any controller action for a more granular approach.

### Detecting Configuration

How you detect an unconfigured app depends on how and where you store your configuration variables. The most common approach is to use an [`IConfiguration` provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), such as `appsettings.json`, which can be combined with the [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0). The [ASP.NET Core Filter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#result-filters) offers a basic example of an options object (`PositionOptions`), mapped to an `IConfiguration` provider (`appsettings.json`), and configured using [ASP.NET Core's Dependency Injection container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

### Setup Page

Since this is typically part of a redistributable library, your setup page will probably be handled via a [Razor Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), which allows you to package Razor views and other assets with your library (e.g., as a NuGet package). Usually, you collect the information from the user that is specific to their installation—such as username, password, and server name—and then use that to establish a connection string, which you then save to the configuration source.

#### Detecting Database

If you don't know the type of database, you'd normally ask as part of the setup page. Though, I suppose, you could also loop through each driver, trying to connect based on the credentials provided, in order to determine which one is successful. But the person configuring the app should probably know what type of database server they installed!

### Conclusion

As mentioned at the top, this is a really broad question, and there are a lot of moving parts. This should help get you started, though, and familiarize you with the main components involved in this process, such as [ASP.NET Core Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0), the [ASP.NET Core Configuration System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), &c.